# If/Else Statement Not Working When Trying To Reformat Subsections

Tags: conditionals

I want my LaTeX code to number sections and subsections like (FYI: I'm using `article` not `chapter` or `book`):

```
0 Introduction (section)
1 A (section)
1.01 A1 (subsection)
1.02 A2 (subsection)
...
1.10 A10
1.11 A11
2 B

However, this is spitting out:
0 Introduction (section)
1 A (section)
1.01 A1 (subsection)
1.02 A2 (subsection)
...
1.010 A10
1.011 A11
2 B
```

Somehow, my if/else statements aren't kicking in.
Anyone knows why?

Code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\setcounter{section}{-1}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Module \arabic{section}}


\ifnum\value{subsection}<10
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.0\arabic{subsection}}
\else 
    \ifnum\value{subsection}<100
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\fi
\fi
\begin{document}

\title{Notes}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\section{A}

\subsection{A1}

\subsection{A2}

\subsection{A3}

\subsection{A4}

\subsection{A5}

\subsection{A6}

\subsection{A7}

\subsection{A8}

\subsection{A9}

\subsection{A10}

\subsection{A11}

\section{B}

\subsection{B1}

\subsection{B2}

\section{C}

\section{D}

\section{E}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `\ifnum` is only evaluated once, precisely at a moment when `subsection` has value 0.

You need the conditional to be evaluated *when* `\thesection` is expanded:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{%
  \thesection.%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}<10
    0%
  \else
    \ifnum\value{subsection}<100
      0%
    \fi
  \fi
  \arabic{subsection}%
}
```

A different solution with `xparse`, which is easily generalizable to any (fixed) padding: we count the number of items in the expansion of `\arabic{subsection}` (that is, the number of digits) and pad accordingly with zeros, in this case to three digits.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\thesubsection}{}
 {
  \thesection.
  \prg_replicate:nn { 3 - \tl_count:f { \arabic{subsection} } } { 0 }
  \arabic{subsection}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_count:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setcounter{section}{-1}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Module \arabic{section}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\thesubsection}{}
 {
  \thesection.
  \prg_replicate:nn { 3 - \tl_count:f { \arabic{subsection} } } { 0 }
  \arabic{subsection}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_count:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\title{Notes}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\section{A}

\subsection{A1}

\subsection{A2}

\subsection{A3}

\subsection{A4}

\subsection{A5}

\subsection{A6}

\subsection{A7}

\subsection{A8}

\subsection{A9}

\subsection{A10}

\subsection{A11}

\setcounter{subsection}{99}

\subsection{A100}

\section{B}

\subsection{B1}

\subsection{B2}

\section{C}

\section{D}

\section{E}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4):

The `\if` condition belongs into the macro definition of `\thesubsection`:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\ifnum\value{subsection}<10 0\fi\arabic{subsection}}
```